# Extend default Less.js functions

Tags: javascript, html, css, less

I am working with less and I want to extend the basic functions of less like rgba() and add my own custom functions. For example hextorgba() which can convert the hex color to rgba directly. I added new function in function.js in less library but it doesn't recognize that function when I try to use it. Can some one help me?

I added the function in function.js file under lib directory. Here is a snippet of functions.js

```
tree.functions = {
    rgb: function (r, g, b) {
        return this.rgba(r, g, b, 1.0);
    },
    hextorgba: function(c){
        return this.rgba(this.red(c), this.green(c), this.blue(c), this.alpha(c));
    },
```

Also I am using the less via command line. I installed the latest less package from npm (npm install less).

Comment: I guess to help we need more details (how exactly you added your function, can we see a code? how do you use the less compiler - e.g. new functions should automatically appear in lessc but not in dist/less.*.js which you need to rebuild, etc. etc.)

Comment: I added the details in the question description. Thanks!

Comment: This way it should just work as soon as you save the file. There's one problem with your code though: LESS will output *any* color value as hex if its opacity is 1.0, i.e. `hextorgba(#123)` will still will output `#112233`. You need to add additional alpha parameter so you can set non-unity alpha and then LESS will output it as `rgba(...)`. More over LESS already has similiar function: `fadeout(#808080, 50)` -> `rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.5)` (the only difference is that its opacity is in reverse)

Comment: So what error message do you get when "it doesn't recognize that function when I try to use it"?

Comment: When I try to compile my LESS file, it says unrecognized input.

Comment: Then we need to see your LESS code. Note that if LESS does not see your function for some reason it actually won't generate any error but just silently will pass the whole string through. So error means you just trying to use some incorrect values/syntax.

Comment: @seven-phases-max I got it working. There was a problem with string escaping as I was trying to use a dynamic  property name based on color value. e.g. badge-orange-light. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 2):

I got this working. There were two problems in the code. First was in the hextorgba(...) function. I had to change it to the following else it was throwing an error "non_object_property_loadError: error evaluating function `hextorgba`: Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

```
hextorgba: function(c, alpha){ // added the alpha parameter for opacity
    var rgb = c.rgb.map(function(c) {return scaled (c, 256); });
    return new(tree.Color)(rgb, alpha);
}
```

The other problem was with the property name. I was trying to use a dynamic property which had a string escaping issue, e.g text-orange. I am getting correct results now.